# A comic story about the edge of the universe being a white fog

Tags: story-identification, comics

This appeared in one of those cheap tie-in comics, almost certainly one of Blake's 7 or Doctor Who, or possibly some Star Wars tie-in, in the early 80s. I'm pretty sure it had an advert for a Star Wars LCD watch on the back cover (most of them did at the time).

The strip would have been at most 4 or so pages. It centred around the captain of a ship, who reached the edge of the universe, where time behaved differently. He got out of the ship and roamed around, getting lost, because everywhere was a white mist. He was calling out for his family.
The last panels panned out to find other alien races' ships which had ended up in the same place, all with people wandering around calling out for their shipmates or friends, who had been there for millions of years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Voyage to the Edge of the Universe](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Voyage_to_the_Edge_of_the_Universe_(comic_story)) is a story from a Doctor Who tie-in comic. Originally published in black and white the UK in 1980/1981, reprinted in color in the US in 1986. No Star Wars LCD watch ad in my copy of the US reprint, but perhaps the original UK edition has one.

The story is 6 pages long, and features a crew of Daemons traveling to the edge of the universe, where their ship comes to a complete stop in a misty white nothingness. The captain leaves the ship and walks into the mist, where he encounters a copy of himself from another universe. The two versions of the captain touch, merging into "the Great One", an immortal "godlike being of **knowledge** and **compassion** ... whose **one thought** was to **return to** and **help** his people! ... But **which** people?"

Because of course each version of the captain has a crew that he could return to, and returning to one would mean abandoning the others. The view pans out to show a line of Great Ones of various alien races, all equally trapped by their inability to solve this conundrum.

Comment: Thanks, this has been haunting me since I was a kid!